# postgresql: alter table add constraint foreign key vs foreign key defined in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am reading migrations of an  existing web app:

```
...
create table BillableTime (
    id int8 not null,
    ...
    project int8,
    primary key (id),
    unique (employee, project, date)
);
...
create table Project (
    id int8 not null,
    ...
    primary key (id)
);
...
alter table BillableTime
    add constraint FK3EBA06E37BE2CBE
    foreign key (project)
    references Project;
```

I do not understand 2 things:
1) why not to use just a simple reference declaration

```
create table BillableTime (
    id int8 not null,
    ...
    project int8 REFERENCES project (id),
    primary key (id),
    unique (employee, project, date)
);
```

What are the benefits of their method?

2) why constraint name is so weird: `FK3EBA06E37BE2CBE`?
Is there a reason for that?

Comment: The name `FK3EBA06E37BE2CBE` is specified by _you_. So why do you ask why it's so weird? It's definitely not one generated by Postgres.

Comment: And why not use the second form? Well in the order you have written, you can't possibly embed the FK in the create for `billabletime` because when that table is created, project does not yet exist

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am reading the source code that is not mine. That  is why I am asking why it is so weird, when I give a constraint name I usually give something descriptive

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you can put the point about project table not yet existing as an answer, as it gives some rational to it. I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) why not to use just a simple reference declaration

Your ORM probably works with MySQL too, and MySQL ignores inline foreign key declarations, so you'd have to do it the long way.

There's less code to support adding foreign keys when you create the table and adding foreign keys later.

> 2) why constraint name is so weird: FK3EBA06E37BE2CBE? Is there a
>   reason for that?

It's perhaps a hash of the referencing and referenced table and column names. Don't forget that sometimes you need to DROP foreign keys, and you have to do so by name. This would make it slightly easier I suppose.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with optimising, just the same but done differently?

Comment: It is most likely not an attempt at optimization, merely compatibility and code simplicity in the ORM

Answer (score 0):

The constraint's name is so weird most likely as a result of using an ORM. I believe, the name of a constraint must be unique throughout the database... so the ORM which has provided the name, aimed to assure uniqueness.
And refering to the first part of your question - it is a result of ORM's migration system implementation - that it generates two statements instead of one... it must have been easier to implement this way - and for Postgres - it does exactly the same